# How to Map a Complex native Query Result Set to a Pojo Class in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My Repository

```
 public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {


           @Query(value = "select mp.*,u.name,p.name, p.ext_id from merchant_product mp join campaign c on c.product_id = mp.id and c.status in (4, 8)join product p on p.id = mp.product_id join user u on u.id = mp.user_id where mp.status = 4 and mp.availability = 'Y';", nativeQuery = true)

            List<Object> getAllProduct();

    }
```

This is my Query in Spring Boot  i am using Spring data JPA . I need to map this to a Pojo class . So that i can use it for further processing .

can anyone help me with this.

My pojo

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    //data of merchant product table
    //data of user table
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String ext_id;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, name = "test", value = "select mp.* ...")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="test", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Product.class,
                columns = {@ColumnResult(name="name"), @ColumnResult(name="id")}, @ColumnResult(name="ext_id")})
})
```

Add the SqlResultSetMapping to initialize mappings which columns from the query corresponding to the Pojo fields

Comment: How do i add it to a method @StansislavL  its says class or method expected , if i add it on top of a method

Answer (score 0):

Id create a constructor for the params you want on Product and call -

```
 public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {
           @Query(value = "select new Product(u.name,p.name, p.ext_id) from merchant_product mp join campaign c on c.product_id = mp.id and c.status in (4, 8)join product p on p.id = mp.product_id join user u on u.id = mp.user_id where mp.status = 4 and mp.availability = 'Y';", nativeQuery = true)
            List<Product> getAllProduct();    
    }
```

You will need to define the params from the wildcard mp.* in your object for mapping

Comment: this dosent work 
the stack trace 

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract

Comment: Sorry _ I hadnt noticed it was a native query as i hadnt scrolled along. Can you map in your JPA model?

Comment: i didnt get you ?

Comment: Its a nativeQuery = true - so raw html - i thought it was jpa

Comment: @Rahul, I have the same use case , Are you able to find a answer to it?